# Paste Macro (File to file) Increase speed

Tags: vba, excel

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Workbooks.Open Filename:="Blah"

Windows("DDD.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("DDDDD").Select
Range("B4:E4500").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Dude").Activate
Sheets("DDDDD").Select
Range("B4:E4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: The macro is slow. is there anyway to speed it up?

Comment: Thats the same thing. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to copy and paste the information without opening the book or make it a lot faster. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  I don't think you will get it any faster while opening the file.

```
Sub Demo()
    ' Declare variables
    Dim wbSrc As Workbook
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim rSrc As Range
    Dim wbDst As Workbook
    Dim wsDst As Worksheet
    Dim rDst As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    ' Avoid Select
    Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="Blah")
    Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Sheets("DDDDD")
    Set rSrc = wsSrc.Range("B4:E4500")

    Set wbDst = Workbooks("Dude") ' Check this, may need to adjust
    Set wsDst = wbDst.Sheets("DDDDD")
    Set rDst = wsDst.Range("B4:E4500")

    ' Avoid clipboard
    rDst.Value = rSrc.Value

    ' restore settings
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

An alternative approach might be to use ADO to query the data from the closed workbook.

Just thought of another appraoch:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet ' <-- Change to your target sheet
    Set rng = ws.Range("B4:E4500")
    rng.FormulaR1C1 = "='Path\To\Your\File\[Blah.xls]DDDD'!RC"
    rng.Value = rng.Value
End Sub
```

This uses the fact that a simple formula referencing a cell in a closed workbook wiil update without opening the workbook.

`ws` references the worksheet you want to put the retrieved data into (`ActiveSheet` in the example, update this to suit your needs).

`rng` is the range in `ws` you want to place the retrieved data.

`rng.FormulaR1C1 = ...` puts a formula in each cell in `rng`.  In this case it references the same cell in the closed workbook.  Build the formula from the full path, file name and sheet name of the closed workbook.  I used `R1C1` style to take advantage of the simple `RC` syntax to get the address of each cell in `rng`

`rng.Value = rng.Value` converts the formulas to values (same as copy, paste values, but faster and smaller).  You could leave the formulas in place if you want.

Comment: HI, Could you explain the second example. So active sheet is your destination? Rng.formular1c1 inputs the file information. and than rng.value is all the values from that sheet?

Answer (score 0):

This post contains several points that may help you. [OZGRID-Optimize Slow VBA Code](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/SpeedingUpVBACode.htm). Several points in the post apply to your case such as: By-passes the Clipboard, Preventing calculation while executing code and stop screen flickering among others.