# can anyone help for code refactoring

Tags: excel, vba

Hi everyone I want to refactor that code but so far i cant think of how to copy and paste all these cells without opening and closing the workbook every time i copy a cell.

```
Sub AllFiles()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    folderPath = "C:\Users\enchevay\Desktop\automation\WeeklyReports\"

    If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath + "\"

    filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.xlsx")
    Do While filename <> ""
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False


       'copy & paste pm
       Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
       Range("F18").Copy
       emptyRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       ActiveWorkbook.Close
       ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(emptyRow, 1), Cells(emptyRow, 19))

       'copy & paste client
       Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
       Range("F14").Copy
       emptyRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       ActiveWorkbook.Close
       ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(emptyRow, 2), Cells(emptyRow, 19))

       'copy & paste project
       Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
       Range("F16").Copy
       emptyRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       ActiveWorkbook.Close
       ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(emptyRow, 3), Cells(emptyRow, 19))

       'copy and paste project type
       Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
       Range("F20").Copy
       emptyRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       ActiveWorkbook.Close
       ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(emptyRow, 4), Cells(emptyRow, 19))

       'copy & paste project stage
       Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
       Range("L20").Copy
       emptyRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       ActiveWorkbook.Close
       ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(emptyRow, 5), Cells(emptyRow, 19))


       'copy & paste budget
       'Range("").Copy


       'copy & paste end date
       Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
       Range("U18").Copy
       emptyRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       ActiveWorkbook.Close
       ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(emptyRow, 7), Cells(emptyRow, 19))

       'copy & paste PM overall
       Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
       Range("AB15").Copy
       emptyRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       ActiveWorkbook.Close
       ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(emptyRow, 8), Cells(emptyRow, 19))

       'copy & paste Overall calc
       Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
       Range("AF15").Copy
       emptyRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       ActiveWorkbook.Close
       ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(emptyRow, 9), Cells(emptyRow, 19))


       'copy & paste Financial
       Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
       Range("AK15").Copy
       emptyRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       ActiveWorkbook.Close
       ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(emptyRow, 10), Cells(emptyRow, 19))


       'copy & paste client
       Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
       Range("AM15").Copy
       emptyRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       ActiveWorkbook.Close
       ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(emptyRow, 11), Cells(emptyRow, 19))


       'copy & paste solution
       Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
       Range("AO15").Copy
       emptyRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       ActiveWorkbook.Close
       ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(emptyRow, 12), Cells(emptyRow, 19))


       'copy & paste Schedule
       Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
       Range("AQ15").Copy
       emptyRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       ActiveWorkbook.Close
       ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(emptyRow, 13), Cells(emptyRow, 19))


       'copy & paste Deliverable
       Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
       Range("AS15").Copy
       emptyRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       ActiveWorkbook.Close
       ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(emptyRow, 14), Cells(emptyRow, 19))

       ' copy & paste resources
       Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
       Range("AK18").Copy
       emptyRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       ActiveWorkbook.Close
       ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(emptyRow, 15), Cells(emptyRow, 19))

       'copy & paste issues
       Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
       Range("AM18").Copy
       emptyRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 16).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       ActiveWorkbook.Close
       ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(emptyRow, 16), Cells(emptyRow, 19))


       'copy & paste risks
       Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
       Range("AO18").Copy
       emptyRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 17).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       ActiveWorkbook.Close
       ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(emptyRow, 17), Cells(emptyRow, 19))



       'copy & paste dependencies
       Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
       Range("AQ18").Copy
       emptyRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 18).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       ActiveWorkbook.Close
       ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(emptyRow, 18), Cells(emptyRow, 19))

       'copy & paste RAG justification
       Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)
       Range("B24").Copy
       emptyRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 19).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       ActiveWorkbook.Close
       ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(emptyRow, 19), Cells(emptyRow, 19))
       Application.ScreenUpdating = True




        filename = Dir
    Loop
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I can help you with the concept. I highly recommend reading Uncle Bobs (Robert C. Martin) book about Clean Code. One of the most important parts of writing good code is "Don't repeat yourself", and keep function/subs short. It's easy to see a pattern in your code, maybe you can wrap that in a different sub.

Comment: I think this should be simple. Can you tell us what you want to do? What ranges from the opened workbook you want to copy and the destination location in the current workbook.

Comment: em I am copying 19 different cells (not ranges).And I am pasting them in the range A1:A19

Comment: Have look at the second suggestion in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20848804/445425) (the one that uses `.FormulaR1C1`)  The idea is that you create a formula to a cell in a closed workbook, then convert it to a value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use loop and close workbook only when you paste *all* values:

```
Sub AllFiles()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim filename As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim cellAddr As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    folderPath = "C:\Users\enchevay\Desktop\automation\WeeklyReports\"

    If Right(folderPath, 1) <> "\" Then folderPath = folderPath + "\"

    filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.xlsx")

    cellAddr = Array("F18", "F14", "F16", "F20", "L20", "", "U18", "AB15", _
        "AF15", "AK15", "AM15", "AO15", "AQ15", "AS15", "AK18", "AM18", _
        "AO18", "AQ18", "B24")
    Do While filename <> ""
        'copy & paste RAG justification
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & filename)

        For i = 1 To 19
            If i <> 6 Then                    
                With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
                    emptyRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                    wb.ActiveSheet.Range(cellAddr(i-1)).Copy .Range(.Cells(emptyRow, i), .Cells(emptyRow, 19))
                End With
            End If
        Next

        wb.Close False
        filename = Dir
    Loop
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Btw, it's better to change `wb.ActiveSheet.` to `wb.Worksheets("SheetName")`.

Comment: That code pastes the values in a column. I want to paste the values from a file in a single row. Then when i open the next file its information should be pasted onto the next empty row.

Comment: it doesnt like that row                wb.ActiveSheet.Range(cellAddr(i - 1)).Copy .Range(.Cells(emptyRow, i), .Cells(emptyRow, 19))

Comment: Sorry, don't understand..what is the problem now?